# Unable to 'git commit --amend' during post-commit with EGIT

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I have a simple post-commit hook:

```
#!/bin/sh
python .git/hooks/post-commit.py
git add "__version__"
git commit --amend -C HEAD --no-verify
```

Which first invokes a file overwrite in post-commit.py

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #
    # Read temp version
    with open("__version__.tmp", "r") as f:
        version = f.read().strip()
    #
    # Write message
    with open("__version__", "w") as f:
        f.write(version)
    #
    # Remove temp file
    os.remove("__version__.tmp")
```

However, I develop and commit using the Eclipse IDE, which (I believe) has its own Java implementation of git, the last line of my post-commit hook `git commit --amend -C HEAD --no-verify` causes an exception:

> Rejected by "post-commit" hook...Unable to create '...git/index.lock' File exists.

I suspect this is because Eclipse's implementation, egit, has opened a lock file, which precludes invoking git in any hooks when committing with Eclipse.

Can someone confirm or deny this? Ultimately, a work around would be great if anyone can suggest one.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, Eclipse uses its own [Git client implemented in Java](http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/). Do you get the error only if Eclipse is running?

Comment: @howlger It's even more specific than that. I get the error only if I make the commit USING Eclipse. If I have Eclipse running and make the commit from cmd, the hook executes fine.

Comment: @howlger Thanks for that confirmation btw. So, I'm wondering if this would be resolved by ensuring that the original commit and the amend are invoked by the same program. Which makes me wonder: (1) can Egit be configured to use my local git executable instead of Jgit or (2) can Jgit be used to make the amend? *thinking face*

Comment: @howlger oddly enough, it lets me access git from if it's in the pre-commit hook. Makes me think the lock must be opened during the commit and sticks around long enough to mess with the post-commit

Comment: (1) no, (2) maybe. I guess the lock is set as long as the hook is executed (independent using the command line Git or JGit). Maybe the solution is that the hook asynchronously(!) triggers the script that does the Git commands. Does your current hook implementation work if you do a commit from the command line (if my guess is correct, that shouldn't work either)?

Comment: From what I remember, it did work otherwise. I'll give it a shot later today to confirm. Thanks!